# Google sheets dsum on blank column criterion

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I'm messing around with google sheets trying to track a goal.

I'd like to run a DSUM() where one of the criteria is that a column is blank.

I have tried `""`, but that isn't working.

I'm trying to get DSUM(A:C, Goal, ) to equal 2 (sums the second column, but not the first) for the following data:

```
Goal   | Met   | Rewarded
------------------------
1      | 1 Jan | 2 Jan
2      | 3 Jan |
3      |       |
```

Where criterion range is:

```
Met   | Rewarded
------------------------
>0    | ""
```

Anyone know how to set the criterion for a blank column? Or use a function like ISBLANK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it with escaping the equal sign:

```
'=
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeeeeeeah, that's the stuff. Thanks!

Comment: How can we do this as not blank?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following formula

```
=DSUM({B2:C6,{D2;ArrayFormula(IFERROR(D3:D6*1,""))}},"Goal",B8:D9)
```

By using `{D2;ArrayFormula(IFERROR(D3:D6*1,""))}` we turn all blank cells to zeros.
So changing the `Rewarded` criterion from `""` to `0` we get the expected results.

[image]

Comment: Another workaround I finally got working is using Filter to find blanks in the desired column, so: `=DSUM(FILTER(B2:D6, {True; ISBLANK(D3:D6)}), "Goal", B8:C9)` and then you don't need to do any criterion on the rewarded column at all.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks for sharing. I think you should turn it to an answer. Not many people make it to the comments.